# Subclassing NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c

I know the first thing to do when one has a question with Obj-C is to read the Apple docs.
And I did. I read p.95-p.102 of the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide. So this is what I know about composite object creation from class clusters.

- Subclassing of class clusters should be done if provided functions need to be modified.
- Composite objects must override primitive methods of the super class. (And I also read that the primitive methods of the super class of the super class have to be overridden as well.)

So I applied what I know.
Here's my code...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GOObjectKeyName : NSMutableString
{
    NSMutableString *embeddedNSMutableString;
}

//+ GOObjectKeyName;

//- init;

//From NSString
- (NSUInteger) length;

// From NSString
- (unichar) characterAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;

// From NSString
- (void)getCharacters:(unichar *)buffer range:(NSRange)aRange;

// From NSMutableString
- (void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)aRange withString:(NSString *)aString;

//- (void) dealloc;

@end



#import "GOObjectKeyName.h"

@implementation GOObjectKeyName

/*
+ GOObjectKeyName
{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        embeddedNSMutableString = [[NSMutableString allocWithZone: [self zone]] init];
    }
    return self;
}
*/

- (NSUInteger) length
{
    return [embeddedNSMutableString length];
}

- (unichar) characterAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index
{
    return [embeddedNSMutableString characterAtIndex: index];
}

- (void)getCharacters:(unichar *)buffer range:(NSRange)aRange
{
    [embeddedNSMutableString getCharacters: buffer range: aRange];
}


- (void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)aRange withString:(NSString *)aString
{
    [embeddedNSMutableString replaceCharactersInRange: aRange withString: aString];
}

/*
- (void) dealloc
{
    [embeddedNSMutableString release];
    [super dealloc];
}
*/

@end
```

The commented methods are commented because I wasn't sure if they were necessary. I just wrote them down because I saw them in the example. And you also might see that it's basically another NSMutableString class. But don't worry, there is a bigger purpose to it, I just want to know that the basics are correct before I continue since this is my first time with composite objects.
And as you know... IT DOESN'T WORK!!
Please understand my frustration after hours of trial and error.
If someone could guide me here it would be a great relief.

Oh, and if you don't mind I have another small question.
The example on the apple docs describe the NSNumber analogy. But is NSNumber actually more efficient then using int, char, and other fundamental types?
Just curious.

Comment: What doesn't work? What did you expect to happen and what actually did happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would certainly help if you would characterize the failure beyond "it doesn't work."

However, your -init method is commented out, so there's no way that `embeddedMutableString` is going to get created. And even if you uncomment it, you call `+alloc` to create `embeddedMutableString`, but you never initialize it.

After looking at [the documentation](http://tinyurl.com/3xso3ya), it seems that a subclass's -init method should look like this (warning: untested code):

```
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        embeddedMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

You will, of course, also have to provide a -dealloc that releases `embeddedMutableString` and calls `[super dealloc]`.

As far as NSNumber, no, it's not more efficient than basic types like int but it does have other advantages. NSNumber is a class, so you can store instances of NSNumber in Cocoa's collection classes such as NSArray and NSSet. You can write them to property lists. NSDecimalNumber avoids the imprecision that comes from converting between decimal and binary notations. And so on...

Comment: I've tried multiple times taking codes out and adding new codes in. But generally it's either bad access or method may not respond to class.

Comment: To be more precise, I can't use the NSString methods, [GOObjectKeyName initWithFormat: @"lol"]; I'm not sure where the message is sent. To self? To NSMutableString? To NSString?

Comment: Well, again, as the code is written you're not properly initializing either `self` or `embeddedMutableString`. Self's `isa` pointer probably isn't set correctly, so self points to a chunk of memory that isn't a real object yet.

Comment: Could you give me a good example of an init method for this case?

Comment: Actually, even before that comment that I just made, are the rules that I know sufficient? Or do I also need the class method, init method, and dealloc method as well?

Comment: See the edited version of my answer above. Please also make sure that you read the Subclassing Notes and Alternatives to Subclassing sections of [the NSString reference page](http://tinyurl.com/3xso3ya).

Comment: so the rules are override the primitive methods and make sure everything is allocated and initialized and then released properly. correct?

Comment: question. why is the -init a void class? shouldn't return an id? and this only creates the embeddedMutableString. what about the GOObjectKeyName class?

Comment: Mistake. Should return id. Sorry for any confusion. As for the rest: -init initializes an instance of whatever class it's part of. If you want to use your GOObjectKeyName class, you'll have to allocate one and then initialize it: `GOObjectKeyName gokn = [[GOObjectKeyName alloc] init];`

Comment: "As for the rest: -init initializes an instance of whatever class it's part of." ---> so do I actually need an init method in my GOKN class, or will alloc-init do everything for me. And another thing, where do these alloc-init method go? to the direct super class or NSObject?

Comment: You need the -init method in your class AND you need to use +alloc/-init to create an *instance* of your class. The first is the definition of the method. The second is where you actually call the method. It's like the difference between defining a word and actually using that word in a sentence. Put your call to +alloc/-init wherever you want to create and use an instance of your class. However, if you're not clear on these basics, you should take a step back and get more comfortable with the language before attempting to subclass a class cluster.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I guess I have to go back to the alloc and init part of the book. I've gotten my questioned answered so I'll continue with your advice. Again, thank you for your time. I'll post a comment again if it works, if not I'll have to ask you another question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your NSNumber question, no, NSNumber is **not** more efficient than the C primitives. NSNumber is an encapsulation for the C primitives, essentialy allowing primitives to be inserted into objects like NSArray and NSSet. If you need that encapsulation ability, but want the speed of an actual **int** or **float**, it's simple enough to write your own NSNumber-like class that works for just one type.

Comment: Thanks, it clears up things. I really didn't understand why they even created this class. Hey, how do I vote or increase your rating?

Comment: Your reputation has to be at least 15 before you can vote answers up. There's a complete list of privileges and associated rep requirements here: [http://stackoverflow.com/privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges)